# Why don't Django and AngularJS follow their MVC patterns when implementing widgets/directives?

Tags: django, model-view-controller, design-patterns, angularjs

Django and Angular follow MVC (this way or another..) patterns, and therefore should separate HTML from code-behind.

But when browsing Django source code you can easily find:

```
class ClearableFileInput(FileInput):
    ....

    template_with_initial = u'%(initial_text)s: %(initial)s %(clear_template)s<br />%(input_text)s: %(input)s'

    template_with_clear = u'%(clear)s <label for="%(clear_checkbox_id)s">%(clear_checkbox_label)s</label>'
```

Instead of write a template and render it with Context.

or

```
def as_table(self):
    "Returns this form rendered as HTML <tr>s -- excluding the <table></table>."
    return self._html_output(
        normal_row = u'<tr%(html_class_attr)s><th>%(label)s</th><td>%(errors)s%(field)s%(help_text)s</td></tr>',
        error_row = u'<tr><td colspan="2">%s</td></tr>',
        row_ender = u'</td></tr>',
        help_text_html = u'<br /><span class="helptext">%s</span>',
        errors_on_separate_row = False)
```

Instead of using templatetags, or use an external template.

---

Same with AngularJS, in their samples on the homepage you find:

```
  this.addPane = function(pane) {
          if (panes.length == 0) $scope.select(pane);
          panes.push(pane);
        }
      },
      template:
        '<div class="tabbable">' +
          '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
            '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">'+
              '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
            '</li>' +
          '</ul>' +
          '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
```

Instead of just using templateUrl and than write the template in a separate file and not inside the code.

Is there a good reason for this? or some other reasonable cause?

I myself don't find one, when writing widgets/directives I manage to separate the html from the code and everything works as expected.

Comment: As an example it looks clearer if all code is bundled together.  There are examples only.

Comment: @asgoth I think that putting html inside javascript string is never clear, but thanks for the comment.

Comment: I know what you mean. I just meant for showing small examples of a particular features it is sometimes better to have have it viewable together, otherwise the learning curve could be even harder. I agree that this shouldnt be used for production code.

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously a bad pattern; in case of django there was an effort to fix it in a GSoC project, but it struggled because django templates are slow, simple string formatting is much faster and using templates for rendering fields was proven to be a real bottleneck. `as_table` looks like a leftover that is kept in source code for backwards compatibility; developers don't need to use it.

I don't have experience with AngularJS, but it may be the case that the template in a separate file mean an extra HTTP request.

Comment: Yes, in angular that means an extra HTTP request, but this is how their framework works, and always it is possible to load all views at first page load (like GWT) to avoid it. about django, for very simple widgets, I see how you can write html as string, but it is not possible when trying to write more complicated ones.